# how to access uitableview cell element outside of "cell for row at indexpath"

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2, ios9

i am using uitableview which have dynamic number of row. (Maximum 4). i am doing localization manually. so when there is one cell localization works perfectlly. but when there is more than one cell my app is getting crash. 
here is my code

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell : customerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customerCell") as! customerCell
    func localcell()
    {
        cell.lblpassegernumber.text = Localization("Passanger1")
        cell.lblSeatNo.text = Localization("SeatNo")
        cell.lblTCnumberL.text = Localization("TcNumber")
        cell.lbltelephonenoL.text = Localization("MobileNumer")
        cell.lblnameL.text = Localization("NameSurname")
        cell.lblemailL.text = Localization("EMailAddress")
    }

    if (indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        localcell()
        email1      = txtemailaddress.text
        telephone1  = txtnameSurname.text
        tcnumber1   = txtTCnumber.text
        name1       = txtnameSurname.text
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 2)
    {
        localcell()
        email2 = txtemailaddress.text!
        telephone2  = txtnameSurname.text
        tcnumber2   = txtTCnumber.text
        name2       = txtnameSurname.text
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 3)
    {
        localcell()
        email3 = txtemailaddress.text!
        telephone3  = txtnameSurname.text
        tcnumber3   = txtTCnumber.text
        name3       = txtnameSurname.text
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 4)
    {
        localcell()
        email4 = txtemailaddress.text!
        telephone4  = txtnameSurname.text
        tcnumber4   = txtTCnumber.text
        name4       = txtnameSurname.text
    }
    return cell
}
```

where am i going wrong. and pls also suggest me if there is any other option to acces uitableviewcell element out side cell for row at indexpath

Comment: The error can help, however there are `!` in `txtemailaddress.text!` can be the problem. Also `localcell()` can called once.

Comment: You have maximum 4 rows so your indexPath.row indexes can be only from 0 to 3

Answer (score 0):

You can  create 1 prototype cell in your story board.in your table view controller do like this

```
 func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dynamicnum.count
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   let cell : customerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customerCell") as! customerCell

    cell.lblpassegernumber.text = Localization("Passanger1")
    cell.lblSeatNo.text = Localization("SeatNo")
    cell.lblTCnumberL.text = Localization("TcNumber")
    cell.lbltelephonenoL.text = Localization("MobileNumer")
    cell.lblnameL.text = Localization("NameSurname")
    cell.lblemailL.text = Localization("EMailAddress")

    return cell

}
```

Comment: what my question is localization working well in first row but while its comes to second row its getting crash.

Answer (score 0):

The `indexPath.row` is `0` for the first row, not `1`. So use this:

```
switch indexPath.row {
case 0:
    // handle first row
case 1:
    // handle second row
case 2:
    // handle third row
case 3:
    // handle fourth row
default:
    break
}
```

Comment: what my question is localization working well in first row but while its comes to second row its getting crash.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making some mistakes in your code, also i'm not getting what exactly are doing by

```
{
localcell()

    email1      = txtemailaddress.text
    telephone1  = txtnameSurname.text
    tcnumber1   = txtTCnumber.text
    name1       = txtnameSurname.text
}
```

What i can do for you is, i can edit your code as below.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath   indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell : customerCell =     tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customerCell") as!     customerCell

    //This is common for all cells so no need to create and call func for this
    cell.lblpassegernumber.text = Localization("Passanger1")
    cell.lblSeatNo.text = Localization("SeatNo")
    cell.lblTCnumberL.text = Localization("TcNumber")
    cell.lbltelephonenoL.text = Localization("MobileNumer")
    cell.lblnameL.text = Localization("NameSurname")
    cell.lblemailL.text = Localization("EMailAddress")

//You were missing indexPath 0 here (not getting what you are doing by this, you could create an array and save dictionary of these values.)
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    email1      = txtemailaddress.text
    telephone1  = txtnameSurname.text
    tcnumber1   = txtTCnumber.text
    name1       = txtnameSurname.text
} else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
    email2 = txtemailaddress.text!
    telephone2  = txtnameSurname.text
    tcnumber2   = txtTCnumber.text
    name2       = txtnameSurname.text
} else if (indexPath.row == 2) {
    email3 = txtemailaddress.text!
    telephone3  = txtnameSurname.text
    tcnumber3   = txtTCnumber.text
    name3       = txtnameSurname.text
} else if (indexPath.row == 3) {
    email4 = txtemailaddress.text!
    telephone4  = txtnameSurname.text
    tcnumber4   = txtTCnumber.text
    name4       = txtnameSurname.text
}

    return cell
}
```

If you want to access cell elements outside, you can do like this

1. If you need to access cell elements inside button action on cell

   @IBAction func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) 
    {

   ```
   CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:tableViewOutlet];
   ```

   NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableViewOutlet     indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
      let thisCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
   }
2. If you want to access subview of cell which is visible

   ```
   let thisCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath.init(forRow: 0, inSection: 0))
   ```

Comment: what my question is localization working well in first row but while its comes to second row its getting crash.

Comment: If you have max 4 cells then it must be getting out of bound error. It is nothing to do with the localization.

Answer (score 0):

ohk.. Finalyy found the issue.   `email1      = txtemailaddress.text`   beacause i declare email1 as complsary means not nil. but when page load textbox was empty so i try to save nil value to email1 and thats the issue. finally solved it.